# UISegmentControl problem

Tags: iphone

i have a UISegmentControl which have 2 segment in my view,the problem is whatever segment i have choosed, it will return 1 in my selectedSegmentIndex property since i want it remain at the first view when select segment 0,the event i used in my segmentcontrol is valueChanged, and the function will be call as show below:
   -(void)segmentSelect:(id)sender{

```
NSInteger select=[sender selectedSegmentIndex];

if(select==0){

    NSLog(@"this is 0");

}
else{
    NSLog(@"this is 1");
    infoViewController *viewController = [[infoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"infoView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

}
can anybody tell what goes wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
 -(void)segmentSelect:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = sender;

    switch ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
            case 0:
                NSLog(@"this is 0");
                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"this is 1");
                            //push the controller
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"this is unexpected");
    } 
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but it returned the same thing,it jus weird.no matter which segment i selected, it will always push the viewcontroller

Comment: Can u add to the question the code that contains the Segmented Control?, maybe we are looking in the wrong place.